# How does Facebook prevent you from putting the site into an iFrame?

Tags: html, facebook, iframe

The following code doesn't work.  How does Facebook do this?  Is there any way around it?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com" width="500" height="500">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because they have `<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny" />` in their source.

Comment: Its not considered reliable. Using X-Frame-Options headers more supported. Read details at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/03/30/combating-clickjacking-with-x-frame-options.aspx

Answer (score 1):

They do this to avoid scams and click jacking. This is impossible to do. It's a security feature that wont be going anywhere...